# How to add React to an existing Electron app?

Tags: reactjs, electron

## How to add React to an existing Electron app?

I have a CLI Node.js application to which I'm intending to add a desktop GUI using ElectronJS and React. I now have succesfully combined the original CLI app and Electron so that when I run `npm start` an Electron powered window pops up and the old app starts doing its thing. **Is there an easy way to add React to the stack or do I need to start my project over with this new architecture in mind?**

Now when I go to the root directory of my project and try to `npx create-react-app` it refuses to initialize because there's already stuff in there. If I create a new subdirectory to my project in which I would then initialize the React app then I'd have `node_modules`, `package.json` etc. duplicates and a weird layered structure which probably isn't the recommended way to go about if it would even work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a subdirectory and run `create-react-app` there. Afterwards, just move the contents up a directory and delete the empty directory.

Example:

```
cp package.json package.json.backup
mkdir temp
cd temp
npx create-react-app test-app
mv test-app/* ..
cd ..
rm -fr temp
```

You can run the above commands in Git Bash if you're on Windows.

Afterwards, you will want to manually merge the `package.json` from `create-react-app` with your old one that's now called `package.json.backup`.

Comment: this doesnt answer the question how can one add react to the project, surely using create-react-app is not the only option.

Comment: There are an infinite number of ways to accomplish this. There is no reason to enumerate them all.

Comment: @WakaChewbacca - "There are an infinite number of ways to accomplish this" interesting... one example would be appreciated.
OP did not ask you to "enumerate them all". Be humble.